# How long does C2DM registration take

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I signed up with C2DM with Google. How long does it take for them to get back to you with your registration id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly instant.  Both times I've registered it was less than 10 minutes to get an email back with the registration information.

Definitely take a look at C2DM example code when you start implementing.  There are a few projects out there that make it a little bit less painful to use (they already implement things like exponential back off on retries, etc).